# Open source web-browser-based CMIS browser

Tags: open-source, cmis

I am looking for a CMIS browser that runs in a web browser.

General requirements:

- Nothing server-side, everything runs in the browser
- Compatible with any CMIS 1.0 and CMIS 1.1 server
- Open source, preferably GNU-LGPL or compatible
- Runs in at least Firefox/Chrome/IE
- Customizable CSS

Required features:

- Browse folders and files, with paging
- Navigation breadcrumb
- Download a file
- Upload a file (if allowed)
- Delete a file
- View metadata
- Edit metadata
- Search the repository by filename
- Search the repository by full text
- File/folder history
- Check-in/check-out

Bonus:

- Show thumbnails if available, icons otherwise
- Upload several files by HTML5 drag-and-drop
- Text file edition
- ACE/policies management

---

[Alfresco HTML5 Client](https://github.com/agea/Alfresco-HTML5-Client) is pretty close, but:

- It is hard-coded to use the Alfresco CMIS server
- Even if I were to modify the hard-coded parts, the login part is Alfresco-specific.

[image: Alfresco HTML5 Client]

---

[Apache OpenCMIS Browser](http://chemistry.apache.org/opencmis-browser.html) is a good start, but it misses many features:

[image: OpenCMIS Browser]